# Can I make the "Text" icon on my Keyguard go to Google Voice?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sms

Ice Cream Sandwich introduces a nifty new keyguard screen:

[image: Keyguard Screencapture]

I love the ability to jump right to the camera and the phone from the Keyguard. However, I don't use Verizon for text messages, I use Google Voice.

can I make the "Text" icon on the Keyguard screen open Google Voice rather then the bilt-in Text message app?